# Use of declared variable in select statment

Tags: mysql

I am trying to execute below query but mysql says `Syntax error: unexpected '@my_var' (at text suffix)`

```
SET @my_var = 1;
INSERT INTO table1(id, myvar)
SELECT * FROM (LAST_INSERT_ID(), @my_var) AS tmp
```

How can I use declared variable in above query?

Comment: The syntax of your `SELECT` statement appears to be off.  There is no table name after the `FROM` keyword.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It is valid. If I feed static value instead of `@my_var` it works. e.g. `SELECT * FROM (LAST_INSERT_ID(), 1) AS tmp` but I need to feed dynamic value using variable.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to select, that you have putted in FROM.

In FROM there must be a table_name and not a column_name or function call.

Comment: I just forgot to put `SELECT`, so the correct way is like this `SELECT * FROM (SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(), @my_var) AS tmp` silly me!